# RUn RTSP Live streaming in all browsers using angular js plugin

Tags: rtsp, live-streaming, browser-support

I have RTSP URL coming from back end and I have to run rtsp live streaming in my web GUI written in angular js.Currently i am using VXG player plugin to run that RTSP URL but this player is only supported in Chrome.Is there any solution to run that rtsp URL in all browsers

E.x: Chrome, Mozilla, IE, Safari, Microsoft Edge?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's great! And the problem is...?

Comment: I am not able to run that rtsp url in all browser.Currently I am using VXG player plugin to run that streaming but that VXG only supported in Chrome. I need something which will play streaming in all browsers.

Comment: Please read this before posting anything more to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I have read. Can you please help me in this issue.

Comment: You haven't. If you had read it, your question would not look like it looks at this moment. Please edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Rtsp is not a supported protocol by most browsers. If you need it to work on all browsers, you must use a protocol that works on all browsers. Like http.

Answer (score 0):

Since RTSP is not supported directly by the browser it needs some back end server which captures the stream using web sockets so it is not like normal http where we need to wait for response web sockets is two-way duplex communication.And again in browser it can play only mp4 videos so there should be player which ever the format the stream is and convert it browser understandable format.

some url which will be helpful understand this concept

https://streamedian.com/docs/#description

And another using node js which uses websocket and jsmpeg player you can implement rtsp streaming in browser using Angular JS

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rtsp-stream

https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg -- jsmpeg player

and server side you should install ffmpeg. so ffmpeg converts your stream.

Note If try to implement Node Js on please install the ffmpeg in the server side